# Link multiple MATLAB GUI's

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I am making a series of GUI's.

On the first GUI, I placed some push buttons. I don't know how to link each button to the other GUI's I have made.

Comment: I think we're going to need more detail to adequately help you. Can you post a (relatively short) code sample?

Answer (score 1):

In this video:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2005/10/03/guide-video-part-two/

I show how you can share data from one GUI to another.  You are also able to call one GUI from another.

Answer (score 0):

I typically recommend the following three general steps when creating a GUI app.

1) Designing the GUI Objects Layout

- Making a list of tasks you want to accomplish using the GUI app
- Creating a sketch of the GUI Layout

2) Defining the Default Properties of the GUI Objects (e.g., 'Visible','Enable','String','Position','Value', etc. of a Button)

3) Defining the Callback Actions of the GUI Objects (i.e., defining what happens when user presses the Button.)